# having trouble with writing a proper sql query

Tags: sql, database, derby

I have a table datatable with following data

```
No  Data
1   access author basic chapter data database information
2   author basic black data chapter creating overview project scope using code 
3   basic data edition author special any assumed been book contained corporation damages
```

I am trying to write a query which does pattern matching with the help of LIKE clause
this is my query

```
rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT No from datatable where Data LIKE '%author basic data%');
```

which is supposed to retrieve all the records that is No 1, 2 and 3 but it returns nothing however

if i execute this query

```
rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT No from datatable where Data LIKE '%author basic%');
```

which gives output as No 1 and 2 but not No 3
so how can i write such a query which gives me the desirable output

thanks in advance

Comment: You should read a bit more about [LIKE operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Answer (score 3):

You query checks if there is a full substring like `%author basic data%`. Try this :

```
SELECT 
   No 
FROM 
   datatable 
WHERE 
   Data LIKE '%author%' AND 
   Data LIKE '%basic%' AND 
   Data LIKE '%data%'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, well is this the efficient way of writing query suppose if i put more data like this Like'%access author special basic chapter data database assumed information%' so will it be the good or is there any efficient way of doing it

Comment: @user2318813 - There is no efficient way of meeting your requirements.  The biggest load in SQL is reading the rows from the disk, once loaded these three `LIKE` expressions are not overly problematic.  Your issue will be that you will ***always*** need to check ***every*** record.  You don't have any scope for creating a useful index; one that would mean that only a few relevant rows need to be loaded from disk.  For that you need a different data structure.

Comment: thanks for your reply, would you give me some links or some basic ideas for writing such kind of different data structure

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have something like

```
CREATE TABLE datatable('No' INT, 'Data' VARCHAR(...))
```

by grouping a lot of attributes together in a single column (`VARCHAR`, `CLOB`, `BLOB`...) you cannot harness the power of SQL.

If you rather do something like

```
CREATE TABLE <meaningful name>('No' INT, AUTHOR VARCHAR(...), TITLE VARCHAR, ...)
```

you avoid using `LIKE` for all your queries and you can, as a commenter said, create indices on the columns most often used to access the data to speed up access.

Other benefits include using aggregating functions on numerical data and joining with other tables.